# Мобильная версия не открывается на IPhone

Tags: css, media-queries

У меня адаптивный сайт на Bootdtrap 4, я использовала отдельно медиа запросы, сайт работает на всех устройствах, кроме последних версий IOS Iphone. Он просто не открывается, браузер говорит, что не может его открыть и показывает пустую страницу. Кто знает, в чем проблема?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

@supports (-webkit-marquee-repetition:infinite) and (object-fit:fill) {
        @supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
 body {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height: 1700px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center , #0c505f, 
      #053540);
      color: #0c505f;
      width: 95vw;
 }
```

Comment: Это не связано с CSS. Проверьте чтобы сайт был доступен по тому адресу который с IPhone откривате.

Comment: а как это проверить? проблема в permission?

Comment: Нужно больше иформации. По какому адресу вы обрящяетесь к сайту на компютере? Какой сервер сы используете для разработки? Пользуетесь ли вы на проекте Gulp или Webpack? Какая у Вас операционая система?

Comment: Адрес всегда один и тот же  geekypanda.fi, на всех устройствах он нормально открывается и работает, проблема только с айфоном.  Я разрабатывала на notepad++.  Я ничего не использую, сайт состоит из index.html, css и файл с javascript. Сайт сейчас у меня на финском хостинге